# How to access classes which are dependencies of the current project in an IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, intellij-idea, classpath

I want to access a class via a dependency (Maven) of the current project. Just like accessing the class in the code window of IDEA.
So, is it possible to access such  classes from a plugin? I can access all project data and classes at the moment, but not the foreign dependencies.

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? You should already be able to see the content of the class (compiled). Do you want to see the code instead?

Comment: I have to use them. E.g. there is a class ObjectUtil in the project root framework, I want to be able to make a call here: ObjectUtil.save(); This class is not in the current project, but in its dependencies.

Comment: Are you writing your own plug-in for IDEA? Do you want to find a class in the dependencies, load it and invoke some methods?

Comment: Get the scope with `com.intellij.psi.search.GlobalSearchScope#moduleWithDependenciesAndLibrariesScope` then use `com.intellij.psi.JavaPsiFacade#findClass` with this scope.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of not understanding the question, if the class in question is a Maven dependency, and if IntelliJ has put the dependency on the classpath, then you just need to import the class to use it:

```
import somepackage.ObjectUtil;
...
ObjectUtil.save();
```

However, it could be the case that the dependency is not a required one - if it is listed as `<optional>true</optional>` or if it has non-compile `<scope>`.

Comment: @Benny you have configured your IDEA project by importing the Maven configuration, right? You can check if the dependency appears under the "External Libraries" item in the Project view. You can also open the "Project Structure" window, select your module in the "Modules" view, and go to the "Dependencies" tab to see if the dependency correctly appears there, with a "Compile" scope.